# New Document option not available in Doucument Library in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, document-library

I have a strange issue with Documents libraries in SharePoint Server 2010.
In all of them I couldn't edit doucment or add new(upload is available, edit properties also)
[image]

I use administrator account with full control permissions.
All libraries inherit permissions from parent site.
Other lists works fine.

Where is the problem?
Thanks in advance, Chris

Comment: Are you managing content types for this document library?  Did you create your own content types to use for this DL?  We don't see the DL contents, but it looks like something is in there. (Manage and Copies sections of the ribbon have active icons.)

Comment: I have fiew libraries with custom content types, but this behaviour is also in standard library like Shared Documents which was never modyfied in any way.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for responses, it turned out that I had got Client Integration disable. Enabled it on resolves the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue:

I solved it by going to Library -> Library settings -> Advanced settings -> Allow management of content types to TRUE.

And i got the NEW document ribbon working for me. Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Check the template for the site content type.  Go to the Site Content Types in the site settings.  Make sure the link to the template exists and is accessible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to disable User Access Control UAC .Check the following article
http://www.petri.co.il/disable-uac-in-windows-7.htm